# Handling all the operations(send Jwt token, cache, loader) in single interceptor is best practice?

Tags: angular

Handling all the operations(send Jwt token, cache, loader) in single interceptor is best practice?
If not what is the reason?

Answer (score 0):

The main concern of Handling jwt tokens in a clientside app, is the security.

- Keep it secret. Keep it safe: The signing key should be treated like any other credential and revealed only to services that need it.
- Store and reuse: Reduce unnecessary roundtrips that extend your application's attack surface, and optimize plan token limits (where applicable) by storing access tokens obtained from the authorization server. Rather than requesting a new token, use the stored token during future calls until it expires. How you store tokens will depend on the characteristics of your application: typical solutions include databases (for apps that need to perform API calls regardless of the presence of a session) and HTTP sessions (for apps that have an activity window limited to an interactive session).

If you can mainly manage these factors properly inside a single interceptor you will be aligned with the best practice.